# Context Path Wildfly 8.2 Management UI

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-8

is it possible, and when how, use the Management UI of the Wildfly 8.2 with a path.

Default: http://localhost:9990/console

How i would like to do it: http://localhost:9990/wildfly/console

Is this possible? And if it is, how?

---

Sub-Context:
i like to have a AJP Proxy that the URL will be http://host/wildfly and not http://host:9990/

Answer (score 0):

[mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) can do that if correctly configured. Something like:

```
ProxyPass /wildfy/             http://localhost:9990/
ProxyPassReverse /wildfly/     http://localhost:9990/
```

Comment: ProxyPass /wildfly/ ajp://localhost:8009/
ProxyPassReverse /wildfly/ ajp://localhost:8009/
 is existing, BUT: it wont run because wildlfy redirect to http://localhost/console and that won't work. As Example Atlassian Products have the options of a context path. so that http://localhost:8080/ could be remapped to http://localhost:8080/jira. i search for this kind of option in Wildfly

Comment: Me, too! I use mod_proxy under mydomain.com/wildfly to configure it and it redirects to mydomain.com/console/...